# mcrypt_get_iv_size issue with one or more Wordpress Plug-ins

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

Environment:
PHP 7.1
Gravityforms 2.2.6 (Current)
Wordpress 4.9.4

From what we can tell, we have some run-away processes (lj4ye4thx86q) that are associated with two WordPress plug-ins (Gravityforms & The Events Calendar & The Events Calendar Pro).

The error shows as the following:

> Deprecated: Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated in /home/lj4ye4thx86q/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/common.php on line 5155. Deprecated: Function mcrypt_create_iv() is deprecated in /home/lj4ye4thx86q/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/common.php on line  5158

**Could this be associated with the run-away processes and if so, what is the fix?**

Comment: The problem with PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are currently maintained and correct. Or go with OpenSSL.

Comment: Not great at PHP, could you provide more detail on I would do this.

Comment: I doubt that `mcrypt_get_iv_size` is your problem. You need to debug your PHP code and find the function that is causing the problem. There is always "cave man" debugging where you add print statements. The ability to debug is an important skill but rarely taught.